# Connect to SQL Server and run query as "passthrough" from Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I currently have code that executes queries on data stored on a SQL Server database, such as the following:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=SQL2SRVR;'
    r'DATABASE=DBO732;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )

sqlstr = '''
    SELECT Company, Street_Address, City, State
    FROM F556
    WHERE [assume complicated criteria statement here]
'''

crsr = conn.cursor()
for row in crsr.execute(sqlstr):
    print(row.Company, row.Street_Address, row.City, row.State)
```

I can't find documentation online of whether pyodbc can (or is by default) running my queries on the SQL Server (as passthrough queries), or whether (if pyodbc can't do that) there is another way (maybe sqlalchemy or similar?) of doing that.  Any insight?

Or is there a way to execute passthrough queries directly from Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with pandas and SQL Server then you should already have created a SQLAlchemy `Engine` object (usually named `engine`). To execute a raw DML statement you can use the construct

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute("UPDATE table_name SET column_name ...")
print("table updated")
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't tell from your proposed answer though whether you're making any claim about whether that kind of approach results in passthrough queries.  In other words, if I do a Select query with a bunch of criteria, where is that criteria evaluated (on the server, or on my local computer)?

Comment: If you use a parameterized SELECT query (presumably with pandas' `read_sql_query`) then the query text and parameter values are sent to the server, evaluated there, and the results are returned to a DataFrame.